# Basic while loop issue

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am creating a simple Tic Tac Toe game with the code provided below. When I run this code I get an invalid syntax error with `True` being highlighted. Shouldn't the While True loop run indefinitely?

```
# Tic-Tac-Toe 
board = [1, 2, 3,
         4, 5, 6,
         7, 8, 9]

def printBoard():
      print (board[0], '|', board[1], '|', board[2], '|' )
      print('- - - - - - ')
      print (board[3], '|', board[4], '|', board[5], '|' )
      print('- - - - - - - -')
      print (board[6], '|', board[7], '|', board[8], '|' )
      print('- - - - - - ')

While True:

move = input('Enter a number from the board?')
move = int(move)

if board[input] != 'x' or board[input] != '0':
    board[input] = 'x'
else:
    print('this spot is taken')

printBoard()
```

Comment: Indentation matters in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `While` shouldn't be capitalized. It should be `while`. Also watch your indents, don't see anything inside that while block.

Comment: I'd appreciate feedback for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

While must be all in lower case: "while". Thats the sintax error

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to remove the empty line between `While True:` and `move = input`

Python cares about every bit of indentation. Also, make sure `while` is lowercase.